# i cant understand the following code

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

```
Matrix<float> trainData2 = trainData.GetRows(intVar >> 1, intVar, 1);
```

intVar is integer type...
please help me to understand this code.

Answer (score 4):

`>> 1` means "shift right one" which is a low-level way of saying "divide unsigned by 2".

Maybe that's the clue you needed?

Comment: It depends what you mean by unsigned... `>>` **does** respect the MSB for signed types. If it was an unsigned divide, I would expect the following (`j` and `k`) to return the same (which they don't): `int i = 1 << 31;int j = (int)(((uint)i) / 2);int k = i >> 1;`.

Answer (score 1):

If the part you don't understand is `intVar >> 1`, this is just shifting the value one bit at the right. In other words, it divides intVar by two.

Answer (score 0):

Well `>> 1` is right shift; in this case, it will (effectively) return halve the value of `intVar` (except for some cases involving -ve numbers). I don't know what your `trainData` is, but I'm guessing we're building a matrix of half of a table or something?